# How can i add class inside content on TWIG - Drupal

Tags: class, drupal, twig

I have this div

```
<div class="col-md-6 column_must">
  <p class="must_title"> {{ content.field_code_must_title }}</p>
  <p class="must_desc"> {{ content.field_code_must_desc }}</p>
</div>
```

I want to insert this 2 class in content, but the result shows the

then the content, but i want the content inside in that

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a twig file to edit the fields field_code_must_title and field_code_must_desc, there you'll be able to add your classes to the fields.

What I would suggest you is on the custom theme folder that you will have on your drupal installation, create the twig files for these two fields and then copy inside the field.html.twig from the drupal core theme and make the changes in place.

Follow this link for more insights:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module